# Log4j2 zipping performance

Tags: log4j2

So I have log4j2 setup to log hourly. I know this happens in a background thread. Unfortunately, our products logs a lot, and zips over 500MB hourly. We notice a small hickup at each hour there is being logged, so it looks like the log4j2 background thread takes too much CPU. It is a small hickup, but unfortunately, this already causes internal errors to our product.

Is there any way to improve the performance of the log4j zipping? Could we for example, say to the background thread, that it is only allowed to use a certain percent of the CPU?

edit:
I've seen CPU usage going through the roof at the moment it happens, so it is definetely a CPU usage thing.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no built-in way to avoid the high CPU usage on rollover so you have to implement that yourself.

log4j2 is designed to be easily extended. I cannot give you a full solution. But you should have a look at the `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.GzCompressAction` class which performs the zipping (in case you are using gz). I think it should be possible to implement your own action class and put a delay to the zipping as you like.

Comment: Nice, I like to have it as an option! Will check it out! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `zip` format allows a “compressionLevel” configuration attribute. This is something you can experiment with to see if it makes a difference. See the DefaultRolloverStrategy parameters in https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender

Another thing to try is simply zip smaller files. You can tell Log4j2 to rollover based on size. You’ll have more smaller log files, but you can post process them offline where it doesn’t disrupt the application.

Comment: Nice, the compressionLevel is certainly worth a shot. The second alinea is something we are also strongly thinking about. Another idea would be perhaps to directly stream it to a zip file. Any experience with that?

Comment: No experience with writing continuously to a ZipOutputStream. It should not be too hard to extend Log4j2’s FileAppender but beware that any small corruption could make the whole log unreadable.